# Is it possible to group objects?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, sprite, layer

Is there a way in Cocos2d to have a group of objects such as sprites, labels, and menus that can be made to undergo an action all together, with only a couple lines of code, so that you do not need to run the action for each different object? I am not talking about layers, but more a group that is within a layer.

Comment: you mean outside of tracking them in an array?

Comment: @nycynik preferably, yes. Or an explaination on how i would move a group of sprites and label using a MutableArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a

```
CCNode *group = [CCNode node];
[group addChild:whatever];
[group addChild:whateverElse];

group.position = newPosition; // will move the group as a block.
group.visible=YES:
```

If you run an action on group like CCMoveTo or CCMoveBy, these actions set the position. Thus you could impart some of the actions to the group as opposed to imparting it individually to each child. For some of the properties you may have to subclass CCNode and propagate in the children using your own logic for these (like opacity).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems to be working. Would this work if i added a layer as part of the group, so then I could move the layer around? I don't think layers can be moved, can you confirm?